# Propulsion thrust vs high winds?

Tags: safety, thrust, weather, launch-window

While I do understand that high wind speed is a risk for space launches (and all air flights), still, is it a physical constraint or a computational problem given we are not dealing with a  hurricane/tornado?

I mean, the thrust of Starship engines should be enough to be able to (auto-)correct the course also under heavy wind?

(question inspired by the recent Starhip SN9 delay)

Comment: Note that the Flight Termination System on Starship is not yet integrated into the vehicle. It is a strap-on part that gets attached to the outside of the vehicle and needs to be manually armed and safed. Also, I believe the body flaps are currently still tied down and need to be released. Both of these require a person to go up on a cherry picker (well over 50m in the case of the nose body flaps!) which have their own wind limits, which are probably lower than what Starship can handle. Also, it's a test campaign, so they don't even know the wind limits yet.

Comment: Are you asking about actual orbital launches or these test hops? There are several questions and answers on the site already about the effects of wind on orbital launches.

Comment: I didn't know that possible course correction is not yet part of the test.

Comment: Wind shear,  cross-wind stability, turbulence,...

Comment: some rockets are flying noodles and though they can withstand incredible axial forces are pretty sensitive to sideways forces that can result from a difference in wind pressure along their length inducing sudden small changes in attitude perhaps. [Why does the CRS-8 Falcon 9 rocket appear to be swaying before launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20980/12102) and  [If not constrained by underpasses, etc., would Falcon 9 have been less of a flying noodle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21669/12102) See also [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33716/12102)